# GTEST : How to pass a List of Arrays as a parameter in ValuesIn of INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I want to pass a list of integer arrays as the container to a parameterised class in GTEST.

For eg:-

```
const int* par_Array[] = {
        { 1, 869, 1200, 1300 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

class testSafetyInterface_failingTestForTargetArrayBoundaryVal :
  public testSafetyInterface,
  public ::testing:: WithParamInterface<int* []>{
};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
        testSafetyInterface_failBoundaryTest,
        testSafetyInterface_failingTestForTargetArrayBoundaryVal,
        ::testing::ValuesIn(par_Array));
```

But i'm failing to understand the syntax and the documentation to do so.

Would be grateful to get any sort of help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const int* par_Array[]` is array of pointers to int const. But it is unclear from the signature of `::testing::ValuesIn`, what is the expected argument?

Comment: As documented at :-  https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h

ValuesIn(container)        - Yields values from a C-style array, an STL
//  ValuesIn(begin,end)          container, or an iterator range [begin, end).

I would like to use the first approach and pass a container which would be my list of arrays.

Comment: you want to use `ValuesIn(const T (&array)[N])` overloaded function right?

Comment: Yes. Where each iteration of the parameterised test will pick one full array from the list .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `const int* par_Array[]` is scalar object and hence multi-braced initialization is not possible.
2. argument for `ValuesIn` is `const T (&array)[N]` so you need to pass array of type `T`

If `T` is of type `int`Array initialization simply looks as follows,

```
int par_Array[] = {1, 869, 1200, 1300 , 1, 1, 1, 1 }; //i.e list of possible input values
```

If `T` is of type `int*[]` array of pointers are expected as argument. And `par_Array` initialization looks like below,

```
int a1[]{};
int a2[]{};
int a3[]{};    
int * par_Array[] = {a1,a2,a3};
```